# Mysql - select from two table as two values

Tags: mysql

I cannot understand why my query

```
SELECT SUM(DATE(date) = '2014-11-2') AS `rate` FROM `ratings` UNION SELECT COUNT(*) AS `users` FROM `user`
```

doesn't create two values - rate, users as in query but only one - rate - with two values.

Result:

```
rate 
6 
10
```

Expected result:

```
rate users
6    10
```

Do you know, what's wrong with my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do a **JOIN** instead of an **UNION**.

Based on the information you shared and the result you want to achieve, your query could look something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(DATE(date) = '2014-11-2') AS `rate`, (
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `user`
)  AS `users`
FROM `ratings`
```

...but this lacks of some relations/conditions between the too tables

Answer (score 1):

Because union is used to 'collect' several rows from different queries into 1 result set:

Something like this might do the trick:

```
SELECT (SUM(DATE(date) = '2014-11-2') AS `rate` FROM `ratings`)
, (COUNT(*) AS `users` FROM `user`)
```

Does that work?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT (COUNT(DATE(date) = '2014-11-2') AS `rate` 
FROM `ratings`), (COUNT(*) AS `users` FROM `user`)
```